# What does this typedef statement do?

Tags: c++, typedef

I was going through some code and am not able to understand the following piece of code. What does it do? What does it mean?

```
typedef void*(*fun)[2];
fun new_array;
```

Comment: It looks like a pointer to an array of two pointers to `void`.

Comment: Use [cdecl.org for questions like this](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=void*%28*fun%29%5B2%5D)

Comment: http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html - `fun` is a pointer to an array of size 2 of `void *`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, basically, this is how `typedef` works: first imagine that the `typedef` isn't there. What remains should declare one or more variables. What the `typedef` does is to make it so that if you would declare a variable `x` of type `T`, instead it declares `x` to be an alias for the type `T`.

So consider:

```
void*(*fun)[2];
```

This declares a pointer to an array of `void*` of size 2. Therefore,

```
typedef void*(*fun)[2];
```

declares `fun` to be the type "pointer to array of `void*` of size 2". And `fun new_array` declares `new_array` to be of this type.

Answer (score 5):

Following the [clockwise/spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html), `fun` is a pointer to an array of two pointers to `void`.